# Finding items with a specific property in array, then counting how many, then creating new array with objects of respective result

Tags: javascript

I have an array of questions (like quizzes), this is the structure:

```
import {SeoCategories} from "../enums/seo";

const initialQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What is Pogo Sticking?",
        category: SeoCategories.analytics,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "The act of visiting a website, then quickly leaving it",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ...",
            },
            {
                choice: "An SEO Tool",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "A way of Working",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "A website that is down",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What tool can you use to track SEO of a website?",
        category: SeoCategories.analytics,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "SEO Spider",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Geometrix",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Pingdom",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Javascript",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What do you mean by Backlink?",
        category: SeoCategories.analytics,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "Incoming Links",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "The incoming links to your website or webpage are referred to as Backlink. It is also called as an inbound link."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 2",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 3",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 4",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is the main purpose of using keyword in SEO?",
        category: SeoCategories.tools,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "Keywords are used by search engines to populate the subjects over the internet",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "Search engine stores keywords in the database, and when a search is done, it will come up with the best possible match."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 2",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 3",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 4",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is keyword stemming?",
        category: SeoCategories.tools,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "The process of finding out new keywords",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "TThe process of finding out new keywords from the root keyword from the search query is referred to as keywords stemming. Adding a prefix, suffix, or pluralization can be used to create the new keyword."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 2",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 3",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 4",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    }
];
```

As we can see, we have 5 questions in this array. 3 of these questions have the category of `Analytics` and then other 2 questions have the category of `Tools`.

`Analytics` = 3 out of 5.
`Tools` = 2 out of 5.

What I want, is to go through this array of questions, and create a new array (or object), that is something like this: `["Analytics": 3, "Tools": 2]` So i can loop through can check the respective category vs total amount of questions, 5.

I am unsure of how to do this. Thank you for your time!

Comment: Try starting with `for(question of initialQuestions ) {console.log(question.category);}` and put some effort into it.

Comment: Who said I have not put effort into it? @Adder

Comment: @CevinThomas How can we possibly know what effort is spent when your attempts at solving the problem were not included in the question? Anyway, js data manipulation questions like these attract lots of answers regardless of if the question was actually well-asked, so you have your solution.

Comment: I understand that you cannot know that, but the other person assumed that I have not, which is blatantly ignorant and rude. I did not include my answers, because they were basic attempts due to my knowledge not being beyond beginner, so it would just clutter up the space and add no value. @Klaycon

Comment: @CevinThomas I understand, I think it's reasonable to assert that it was rude. However I disagree on your last point, adding your attempt is helpful because it allows answerers to point out exactly where your attempt was insufficient, which helps you learn what kind of approach to take next time. As it is now, you have merely asked for and received the exact code you need - this is a situation that prevents learning.

Comment: That is a very good point, did not see it from that view. My method of learning was always to recieve the answer, and then pick the code apart in a sandbox to learn step by step what the function did (in this case, every chose to say reduce). I will keep that in mind next time, thank you @Klaycon

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use [`reduce`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Array/Reduce) on the array and build a new object with those keys/totals.

(I added the `SeoCategories` object because that was missing from your question).

```js
const SeoCategories = {
  analytics: 'Analytics',
  tools: 'Tools'
}

const initialQuestions = [{
    question: "What is Pogo Sticking?",
    category: SeoCategories.analytics,
    options: [{
        choice: "The act of visiting a website, then quickly leaving it",
        isCorrect: true,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ...",
      },
      {
        choice: "An SEO Tool",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "A way of Working",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "A website that is down",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What tool can you use to track SEO of a website?",
    category: SeoCategories.analytics,
    options: [{
        choice: "SEO Spider",
        isCorrect: true,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Geometrix",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Pingdom",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Javascript",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What do you mean by Backlink?",
    category: SeoCategories.analytics,
    options: [{
        choice: "Incoming Links",
        isCorrect: true,
        explanation: "The incoming links to your website or webpage are referred to as Backlink. It is also called as an inbound link."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 2",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 3",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 4",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What is the main purpose of using keyword in SEO?",
    category: SeoCategories.tools,
    options: [{
        choice: "Keywords are used by search engines to populate the subjects over the internet",
        isCorrect: true,
        explanation: "Search engine stores keywords in the database, and when a search is done, it will come up with the best possible match."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 2",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 3",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 4",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."

      }
    ]
  },
  {
    question: "What is keyword stemming?",
    category: SeoCategories.tools,
    options: [{
        choice: "The process of finding out new keywords",
        isCorrect: true,
        explanation: "TThe process of finding out new keywords from the root keyword from the search query is referred to as keywords stemming. Adding a prefix, suffix, or pluralization can be used to create the new keyword."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 2",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 3",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      },
      {
        choice: "Option 4",
        isCorrect: false,
        explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
      }
    ]
  }
];

// Iterate over the array
const out = initialQuestions.reduce((acc, c) => {

  // Destructure the category from the current answer
  // in the iteration
  const { category } = c;

  // If the category doesn't exist on the accumulator object
  // assign it zero, and then add one, otherwise just add one
  acc[category] = (acc[category] || 0) + 1;

  // Return the accumulator for the next iteration
  return acc;
}, {});

console.log(out);
```

Comment: you can perform the destructuring right in the parameter list: `.reduce((acc, {category}) => { acc[category] = ... })`

Comment: You're right but I like to define each step in my examples for practical reasons.

Answer (score 2):

This should make the task:

```
initialQuestions.reduce((a,b) => {a[b.category]? a[b.category]++:(a[b.category] = 1);return a}, {});
console.log(res);
```

```js
const SeoCategories = {analytics: "Analitics", tools: "tools"};
const initialQuestions = [
    {
        question: "What is Pogo Sticking?",
        category: SeoCategories.analytics,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "The act of visiting a website, then quickly leaving it",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ...",
            },
            {
                choice: "An SEO Tool",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "A way of Working",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "A website that is down",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What tool can you use to track SEO of a website?",
        category: SeoCategories.analytics,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "SEO Spider",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Geometrix",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Pingdom",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Javascript",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What do you mean by Backlink?",
        category: SeoCategories.analytics,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "Incoming Links",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "The incoming links to your website or webpage are referred to as Backlink. It is also called as an inbound link."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 2",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 3",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 4",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is the main purpose of using keyword in SEO?",
        category: SeoCategories.tools,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "Keywords are used by search engines to populate the subjects over the internet",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "Search engine stores keywords in the database, and when a search is done, it will come up with the best possible match."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 2",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 3",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 4",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."

            }
        ]
    },
    {
        question: "What is keyword stemming?",
        category: SeoCategories.tools,
        options: [
            {
                choice: "The process of finding out new keywords",
                isCorrect: true,
                explanation: "TThe process of finding out new keywords from the root keyword from the search query is referred to as keywords stemming. Adding a prefix, suffix, or pluralization can be used to create the new keyword."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 2",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 3",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            },
            {
                choice: "Option 4",
                isCorrect: false,
                explanation: "This is incorrect due to ..."
            }
        ]
    }
];
const res = initialQuestions.reduce((a,b) => {a[b.category]? a[b.category]++:(a[b.category] = 1);return a}, {});
console.log(res);
```

Comment: if the goal is just brevity, you can make this much shorter: `initialQuestions.reduce((a,{category}) => (a[category] = -~a[category]) && a, {});`